# Concerns about code on Linux high-performance servers

Tags: c++, parsing

Today I read the Linux High Performance Server book, and I had some concerns about the code in the book：

```
LineStatus parseLine(char* buffer, int& checkedIndex, int& readIndex) {
    char temp;
    for(; checkedIndex < readIndex; ++checkedIndex) {
        temp = buffer[checkedIndex];
        if(temp == '\r') {
            if(checkedIndex + 1 == readIndex) {
                return LINE_OPEN;
            } else if(buffer[checkedIndex + 1] == '\n') {
                buffer[checkedIndex++] = '\0';
                buffer[checkedIndex++] = '\0';
                return LINE_OK;
            }
            return LINE_BAD;
        } else if(temp == '\n') {
            if(checkedIndex > 1 && buffer[checkedIndex - 1] == '\r') {
                buffer[checkedIndex - 1] = '\0';
                buffer[checkedIndex++] = '\0';
                return LINE_OK;
            }
            return LINE_BAD;
        }
    }
    return LINE_OPEN;
}
```

For the above code，I don't understand why else if(temp == '\n')，

What is the purpose of this else branch？

I have asked gpt for answer, but I still don't know why

Comment: At a quick glance, it looks like it accepts both Windows style CRLF line endings and Unix style LF ones

Comment: I don't thinkso , @Shawn.  Look more carefully: both branches are checking for a CR / LF pair.

Comment: @OP In order to understand this code, you need to look at what the caller does when LINE_OPEN is returned.

Comment: @Shawn This is probably server code that parses an HTTP header. HTTP mandates CR/LF pairs as line endings in the header. That's why the code returns `LINE_BAD` if it finds a LF without a preceding CR.

Comment: @user3386109, `LINE_OPEN` is a signal that the buffer contains a partial line, and that `parse_line` should be called again after reading more.

Comment: `int& checkedIndex`?  Huh?  That's not C code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the second `if(temp == '\n')`, it would allow lines to contain a  Line Feed elsewhere than at the end.

---

`\r` is Carriage Return (CR), and `\n` is Line Feed (LF).

`parseLine` finds a line terminated by the two-character sequence CR+LF in the buffer.

It's a validating parser, meaning it doesn't assume valid data and checks for errors. Specifically, it reports the presence of a lone CR or of a lone LF as an error.

When it encounters a CR (line 5), it check if it's followed by a LF (line 8) This catches a missing LF.

When it encounters a LF (line 14), it check if it's preceded by a CR (line 15). This catches a missing CR.

Answer (score 1):

> For the above code，I don't understand why else if(temp == '\n'),

I think you're observing that the `if(temp == '\r')` branch checks for a trailing newline character, and the `else if(temp == '\n')` branch checks for a preceding carriage return character.  Surely the latter is redundant then, right?

Wrong.  Study the code carefully.  Observe:

- the loop does not initialize `checkedIndex`, but instead uses the value passed in
- `checkedIndex` is a reference, so changes made to it inside the function will be visible to the caller
- when a `'\r'` is observed on the last possible iteration of the loop, the return value is `LINE_OPEN`, which is the same value returned when neither a newline nor a carriage return is observed at all.

The contents of the `else if(temp == '\n')` make sense if that branch can be entered on the first iteration of the loop *on a given call to the function*, with `checkedIndex` greater than 0.  That would provide for recognizing and handling CR/LF pairs that are split across two consecutive calls to the function.  That could happen when the caller is processing an incoming stream of (supposed-to-be) CR/LF delimited data in chunks that are not necessarily aligned on line boundaries.

The function finds and reports CR/LF line terminators, and separately reports bare CRs and bare LFs.  Including when a CR/LF pair is split across chunks, such as when they are obtained from different `read()` calls.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Just say something to a dreamer. Thank you so much